# What is the negation of ((If G, then B) or D)?

Tags: geometry, logic

I was wondering the answer to the negation of the conditional ((If G, then B) or D). Preferably, the answer would be in English/conditional format.

Comment: Have you made any progress yourself? Do you know how to negate a statement like "$A$ or $B$"? And how to negate a statement like "if $A$, then $B$"?

Comment: Yes, I do. Just wondering how to negate ((If G, then B) or D). A combination of the two.

Comment: In that case, you just negate the statement "$A$ or $B$" where $A$ is "if $G$, then $B$" and $B$ is "$D$" first, and then keep going until you've run out of things to negate `:)`

Comment: Yup. I got the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is the following:

$$\neg((G\rightarrow B)\vee D)=\neg(G\rightarrow B)\wedge \neg D=(G\wedge \neg B)\wedge \neg D.$$

First equality is De Morgan's law, second is just a little theorem that you can prove with a truth table: $\neg(A\rightarrow B)=A\wedge\neg B$.

In english the answer is:

$$G \,\,\text{and}\,\, (\text{not} \,\,B) \,\,\text{and}\,\, (\text{not} \,\,D).$$

Comment: Thanks! Translating that to English would be ((G and not B) and not D). I came to this conclusion myself, just needed a verification.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry I edit that. Your answer is correct anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Show that (If G, then B) is equivalent to (not G or B). This implies that your statement is equivalent to ((not G or B) or D). What's the negation of a disjunction?

Comment: Ah thank you. So when you negate that, you get ((G and not B) and not D) just as @Bellem said.